# On this tikz-qtree when I color the nodes the parent node gets covered. How to fix it?

Tags: tikz-qtree

```
\documentclass{article}  
\usepackage{tikz}  
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}  
\usetikzlibrary{trees} % this is to allow the fork right path  
\pagecolor{olive!50!yellow!50!white}  
\begin{document}  

\begin{tikzpicture}[level distance=1.25in,sibling distance=.25in,scale=.75]
\tikzset{edge from parent/.style= 
            {thick, draw,
                edge from parent fork right},every tree node/.style={draw,minimum width=1in,text width=1in, align=center,fill=white},grow'=right}  
\Tree   
    [. parent   
        [.{nice child0}  
                [.{grandchild0-0 } ]  
            [.{grandchild0-1 } ]  
            [.{grandchild0-2 } ]  
            [.{grandchild0-3 with a really long name } ]  
        ]  
        [.child1  
                [.{grandchild1-0 } ]  
            [.{grandchild1-1 } ]  
            [.{grandchild1-2 } ]  
        ]   
        [.child2 ]  
        [.child3 ]  
    ]  
\begin{scope}  
\tikzset{edge from parent/.style= 
            {thick, draw,
                edge from parent fork left},every tree node/.style={draw,minimum width=1in,text width=1in, align=center,fill=white},grow'=left}  

\Tree   
    [.\node[draw=none]{};   
        [.{nice child0}  
                [.{grandchild0-0 } ]  
            [.{grandchild0-1 } ]  
            [.{grandchild0-2 } ]  
            [.{grandchild0-3 with a really long name } ]  
        ]  
        [.child1
                [.{grandchild1-0 } ]  
            [.{grandchild1-1 } ]  
            [.{grandchild1-2 } ]  
        ]   
        [.child2 ]  
        [.child3 ]  
    ]  

\end{scope}  
\end{tikzpicture}  
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has to do with how you overlay your tree nodes. Notice that TikZ draws the first nodes and sets the parent node and subsequently draws on top of that; hence, the way you had it, TikZ would fill draw and empty box on top of your label. Therefore, switching the order in which it is drawn solves the problem.

[image]

See the MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}  
\usepackage{tikz}  
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}  
\usetikzlibrary{trees} % this is to allow the fork right path  
\pagecolor{olive!50!yellow!50!white}  
\begin{document}  

\begin{tikzpicture}[level distance=1.25in,sibling distance=.25in,scale=.75]
\tikzset{edge from parent/.style= 
            {thick, draw,
                edge from parent fork right},every tree node/.style={draw,minimum width=1in,text width=1in, align=center,fill=white},grow'=right}  
\Tree   
    [.{}   
        [.{nice child0}  
                [.{grandchild0-0 } ]  
            [.{grandchild0-1 } ]  
            [.{grandchild0-2 } ]  
            [.{grandchild0-3 with a really long name } ]  
        ]  
        [.child1  
                [.{grandchild1-0 } ]  
            [.{grandchild1-1 } ]  
            [.{grandchild1-2 } ]  
        ]   
        [.child2 ]  
        [.child3 ]  
    ]  
\begin{scope}  
\tikzset{edge from parent/.style= 
            {thick, draw,
                edge from parent fork left},every tree node/.style={draw,minimum width=1in,text width=1in, align=center,fill=white},grow'=left}  

\Tree
    [.{parent}   
        [.{nice child0}  
            [.{grandchild0-0 } ]  
            [.{grandchild0-1 } ]  
            [.{grandchild0-2 } ]  
            [.{grandchild0-3 with a really long name } ]  
        ]  
        [.child1
                [.{grandchild1-0 } ]  
            [.{grandchild1-1 } ]  
            [.{grandchild1-2 } ]  
        ]   
        [.child2 ]  
        [.child3 ]  
    ]  

\end{scope}  
\end{tikzpicture}  
\end{document}
```